# How can I use sed to put spaces in between consecutive characters?

Tags: sed

I have been trying to write a bash script that converts csv files into confluence tables.

I would like a sed command (or several) that converts:

```
one,two,,three
```

into

```
|one|two| |three|
```

Note that it needs a space when there is no data.

I have been struggling to find anything that works.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example:

```
# first, replace comma with pipe
y/,/|/
# loop, replacing consecutive pipes
:loop
s/||/| |/
tloop
```

Alternatively, you should be able to `s/||/| |/g` twice, as all the `||` missed by the first one (due to the start overlapping the end of the previous substitution) will be caught by the second.

Comment: yes I used the second option twice and it worked thanks!